# NotReadableError in WebRTC with Safari 12

Tags: javascript, video, safari, webrtc

I have a strange issue in Safari 12 when trying to start a local video feed. Everything works in Safari 11, no errors at all. Calls to `getUserMedia` are ok, all codecs are correct but when using 12 I get the following error in the JS console:

`WARN" – "in" – "[createLocalTracks #1]:" – "Call to getUserMedia failed:"
NotReadableError: The I/O read operation failed.`

What could this issue mean? Does it mean it's having trouble assigning the tracks? Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got a `NotReadableError` on mobile safari when my constraints were wrong or overconstrained. I added a `echoCancellation: true` on the audio constraint and the safari browser didn't like it. Same thing happened if I added a `deviceId` constraint. Not sure why though, since it's supported by Safari...

Comment: Tim: thanks for your comment, I think this is primarily with older versions of Safari -- when I enabled the "experimental" mode for web/video it seemed to be ok.